# Java: Connections to HBase with HTable - handling of connection loss

Tags: java, hadoop, connection, hbase

I have got one question. I use a Java program to write data in my HBase. I have HTable Objects there and I call the following methods (pseudo code):

```
// creates a Put object with new data
Put put = createNewPutObject(); 
htable.put(put);
htable.flushCommits();
```

clearBufferOnFail is set to true:

`this.htable.setAutoFlush(false, true);`

The first part of the code is called over and over again. We do something, create a Put object, flush the htable, do something more, create a Put object... and so on.

What happens if my HTable Object loses the connection to the HBase? Is this handled internally? Or do I need to close my HTable Object and to open a new HTable object then?
Until now I thought that connections are handled from the HTable Object internally with a connection pool, so that I done have to do anything. I thought it would be enough to catch an exception and then to retry. As clearBufferOnFail is set to true, no duplicated data would be written.

But can it happen that too many Connections are open somehow? Or is this all handled?

Comment: What's the type/class of `htable`?

Comment: Its org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable and I use Version 0.90.4-cdh3u3 of org.apache.hbase